# RegEx for filling up string

Tags: javascript, regex, extendscript

I have the following input:

```
123456_r.xyz
12345_32423_131.xyz
1235.xyz
237213_21_mmm.xyz
```

And now I need to fill up the first connected numbers to 8 numbers leading with 0:

```
00123456_r.xyz
00012345_32423_131.xyz
00001235.xyz
00237213_21_mmm.xyz
```

My try was to split a the dot, then split (if existing) at the underscore and get the first numbers and fill them up.

But I think there will be a more efficient way with the regex replace function with just the one function, right? How would this look like?

TIA
Matt

Comment: I don't think there is regex for doing this, and the js code to do it is very short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a regex, but just for the spliting :

```
 var input = "12345_32423_131.xyz";
 var output = "00000000".slice(input.split(/_|\./)[0].length)+input;
```

Result : `"00012345_32423_131.xyz"`

**EDIT :**

the fast, no-splitting but no-regex, solution I gave in comments :

```
"00000000".slice(Math.min(input.indexOf('_'), input.indexOf('.'))+1)+input
```

Comment: If you want an optimized version, replace the spliting with the min of `indexOf('_')` and `indexOf('.')`. But then my answer has no regex...

Comment: It works but can u explain what this does: `split(/_|\./)` ? TIA

Comment: It splits the string with `_` or `.` as separator in order to get the length of the first integer. It's the most concise but if you really need the fastest solution, use `"00000000".slice(Math.min(input.indexOf('_'), input.indexOf('.'))+1)+input;`

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't split at all, just replace:

```
"123456_r.xyz\n12345_32423_131.xyz\n1235.xyz\n237213_21_mmm.xyz".replace(/^[0-9]+/mg, function(a) {return '00000000'.slice(0, 8-a.length)+a})
```

Comment: not sure if a replace or the version from @dystroy is better :)

Comment: That really depends if you want to get a string as a result or array of strings. My approach is cleaner I would say :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple regexp to find the part of the string you want to replace, but you'll need to use [a replace function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to perform the action you want.

```
// The array with your strings
var strings = [
    '123456_r.xyz',
    '12345_32423_131.xyz',
    '1235.xyz',
    '237213_21_mmm.xyz'
];

// A function that takes a string and a desired length
function addLeadingZeros(string, desiredLength){
    // ...and, while the length of the string is less than desired..
    while(string.length < desiredLength){
        // ...replaces is it with '0' plus itself
        string = '0' + string;
    }

    // And returns that string
    return string;
}

// So for each items in 'strings'...
for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i){
    // ...replace any instance of the regex (1 or more (+) integers (\d) at the start (^))...
    strings[i] = strings[i].replace(/^\d+/, function replace(capturedIntegers){
        // ...with the function defined above, specifying 8 as our desired length.
        return addLeadingZeros(capturedIntegers, 8);
    });
};

// Output to screen!
document.write(JSON.toString(strings));
```